# Is there a way I can get the table to not resize in height when I innerHtml something in the "td"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I am sorry for the norwegian variable names in the js file, but if u try to click a cell, you will see that the height of it will resize, I am wondering if anyone have an easy and quick change!**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="no">
 <head> 
    <title> Standardoppsett </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 
<style>

.board {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 360px;
  height: 360px;
  border: 32px solid;
  border-color: darkslategray;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.firkant {
  border: 1px black solid;
}
.hvit{
  background:white;
}
.svart{
  background:grey;
}
td:hover {
  background: lightgreen;
  cursor: pointer
}

</style>

<body>

<div>

<table class="board"></table>

</div>

<script>

let tableEl = document.querySelector("table")

for(let i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
  let trEl = document.createElement('tr');
  for(let j = 1; j < 9; j++) {
    let tdEl = document.createElement('td');
    tdEl.setAttribute("id","rute"+i+j)
    tdEl.addEventListener("click",plasserDronning)
    trEl.appendChild(tdEl);
    // Bare på grunn av css
    tdEl.className = (i%2 === j%2) ? "hvit firkant" : "svart firkant";
    }
  tableEl.appendChild(trEl);
}

turTeller = 0

function plasserDronning(e){
  let firkantTrykket = e.target
  console.log(firkantTrykket.id)
  if (turTeller == 0) {
    if(firkantTrykket = e.target){
      firkantTrykket.innerHTML = "a";
  }
    turTeller = 1
  }
  else if(turTeller == 1) {
    if(firkantTrykket = e.target){
      firkantTrykket.innerHTML = "b";
  }
    turTeller = 2
  }
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So far I have tried basically everything I am aware of, I have tried to set the table layout to fixed, I have tried to set the "td's" posistion to top and a lot more, if anyone knows what I can do, it would mean a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In above code I suggest to add height properties in you td tag's class that will solve your issue.
if you want to more responsive and you can write [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).or using other framework like [bootstap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/index.php).

```
.hvit{
  background:white;
  height:20px;
}
.svart{
  background:grey;
  height:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `height:calc(100% / 8);` to the `firkant` (td) class to prevent the cell from growing.

This way the cell will scale with the table if you decide to increase the table size or make it dynamic.